# Kotlin button array

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, button

I really hope this question has not been answered everywhere else already but every search seems to focus on listeners and other uses of a button array but i want to also use it for formatting all buttons at the same time (activate, deactivate etc)

So here is what I have tried;

```
val buttons = arrayOf(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4)
```

This will work, BUT will only change a single button

```
buttons[0].isEnabled=true; //
```

Then this is the bit that I am struggling with;

```
buttons[0..buttons.size].isEnabled=true;
```

The response is basically that it expects a single number and not a range.

I also tried;

```
buttons[].isEnabled=true;
```

The response is that it requires an index

I also tried

```
buttons.isEnabled=true;
```

This of course will not resolve properly

My key question really is can I apply formatting/state changes to all using an array or will I always have to do it for each button in turn?

I think it would be possible to create a loop but that isn't the route I wanted to follow here if there is an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there is a way mate. You gotta loop and regardless of what syntatic sugar a language has in the end its still a for loop.

You could do:

```
buttons.forEach {
    it.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Is the "it" meant to be replaced with anything?  Like a counter? If I use the code as per your suggestion "enabled" reference does not resolve any longer

Comment: @Karl Griffiths please see my updated answer, sorry used the wrong property,  should be `isEnabled` and not `enabled`

Comment: doh! I should have noticed that as well. Thank you. Also you are right this is a loop like any other and ultimately what I was describing as needed, I had a much more long winded view of the loop in my head than would have been worth it which is what I wanted to avoid. I had no idea I could write it so simply. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: @Karl Griffiths no problem mate, and Kotlin is a very "sexy" language syntactically in my opinion when compared to Java and even C#. But yeah as you learn the language more it will grow on you even further 